# Add (subtract) months without exceeding the last day of the new month

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I am looking to add and subtract six months (bond time) reliably with `lubridate`.

For example, adding six months to `12/31/2014` should result in `6/30/2015`,
and adding to `2/28/2014` should result in `8/31/2014`

The issue with `as.Date("2014-12-31") + months(6)`, is that it yields an `NA`. Alternatively, the second result is 8/28/2014 because it doesn't just add 6 months to the month and then know where the day should end up dependent upon the month.

Is there any way to quickly correct this? At the moment, I am building a function to basically use a switch and consider each month, but this is very long and I am having problems with it as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Not really clear on the behavior you want - what should adding 6 months to 2/27/2014 give?  8/30/2014, or 8/27/2014?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The `lubridate` function `%m+%` may be useful here:

> Add and subtract months to a date without exceeding the last day of the new month

```
as.Date("2014-12-31") %m+% months(6)
# [1] "2015-06-30"
```

To also handle the second case, you will need to round up to nearest month using `ceiling_date`, and subtract one day using `days`.

```
ceiling_date(as.Date("2014-02-28") %m+% months(6), unit = "month") - days(1)
# [1] "2014-08-31"
```

Answer (score 2):

I just coded this out quickly, but I think it should work. I'm not sure if it's the most elegant solution, however.

```
# up = 1, down = -1
six.mo.mover<-function(date,up.or.down) {
  last.day <- month(date) != month(as.Date(date)+1) 
  if(last.day) {
    adj.date <- as.Date(date) - day(as.Date(date)-1) + up.or.down*months(6)
    adj.mo <- month(adj.date)
    if (adj.mo == 2) {
      dy <- 28 + leap_year(year(adj.date))
    }
    else {
      dy <- 31-(adj.mo-1)%%7%%2
    }
    adj.date + days(dy-1)
  } 
  else {
    as.Date(date)+up.or.down*months(6)
  }
}
```

*NB: not debugged, so check it yourself and let me know.*

Answer (score 2):

`tidyverse` has added the [clock](https://clock.r-lib.org/) package *in addition* to the `lubridate` package that has nice functionality for this:

```
library(clock)

x <- as.Date("2014/12/31")

# The previous valid moment in time
add_months(x, 6, invalid = "previous")
[1] "2015-06-30"

# The next valid moment in time
add_months(x, 2, invalid = "next")
[1] "2015-03-01"

# Overflow the days. There were 28 days in February, 2015, but we
# specified 31. So this overflows 3 days past day 28.
add_months(x, 2, invalid = "overflow")
[1] "2015-03-03"
```

The `invalid` argument makes explicit what to do in this case. You can also specify `invalid` to be `NA` or if you leave off this argument you could get an error.

---

For the second use case:

> adding [6 months] to 2/28/2014 should result in 8/31/2014

You can use `calendar_end`, which needs a *calendar vector*:

```
year_month_day(2014, 02, 28) |> 
  add_months(6) |>
  calendar_end("month")

<year_month_day<day>[1]>
[1] "2014-08-31"
```

---

Alternatively, you could sequence the dates and select out the dates with the appropriate number of months added (or subtracted):

```
dates <- date_build(2014, 1:12, 31, invalid = "previous")

dates[c(2,8)]
# [1] "2014-02-28" "2014-08-31"
```