# sqldf query with date difference

Tags: r, date, merge, difference, sqldf

I am trying to perform a (simplified!) query on colour and date differences on the following two databases (extract):

```
A                           B   
    A.COL   A.TIME              B.COL   B.TIME
1   blue    2009-01-31      1   blue    2007-01-31
2   blue    2009-02-28      2   blue    2008-12-31
3   blue    2009-03-31      3   blue    2009-02-28
4   blue    2009-04-30      4   blue    2009-04-30
5   blue    2009-05-31      5   blue    2009-06-30
6   blue    2009-06-30      6   blue    2016-08-31
7   blue    2016-03-31
8   blue    2016-04-30
9   red ...
10  red ...
```

What I want to do: Merge the tables based on COL as well as the difference in TIME, that is the difference betweeen both times must not be larger or lower than 2 month (or in other words lie between -2 and +2, depending from which date one starts with).

```
# For example starting with observation 1 from A, that would imply 2 matches:
2009-01-31 matched to 2008-12-31 (diff = 1)
2009-01-31 matched to 2009-02-28  (diff = -1)

# for obs 2 from A, that would imply 
2009-02-28 matched to 2008-12-31 (diff = 2)
2009-02-28 matched to 2009-02-28 (diff = 0)
2009-02-28 matched to 2009-04-30 (diff = -2)
```

etc.
I was thinking about some kind of Date difference function, either from `lubridate`, which was problematic in cases of months with less than 30 days and sometimes made NAs, or with `as.yearmon` from `zoo`, which worked to correctly calculate the differences at least. However, I wasn't able to implement this into `sqldf` properly (Error: error in statement: near "as": syntax error). The reason seems to be that one cannot use every R function withing sqldf.
Any ideas how it can be done in R? I was also looking for an elegant way of how to subtract months from each other. There is this issue with lubridate:
[Add/subtract 6 months (bond time) in R using lubridate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628863/add-subtract-6-months-bond-time-in-r-using-lubridate), but here was one proposed way how to accomplish it with `zoo`: [Get the difference between dates in terms of weeks, months, quarters, and years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454476/get-the-difference-between-dates-in-terms-of-weeks-months-quarters-and-years)

Get the data (thanks @bouncyball below for the code):

```
A <- read.table(
  text = "
  A.COL   A.TIME          
  blue    2009-01-31     
  blue    2009-02-28      
  blue    2009-03-31      
  blue    2009-04-30      
  blue    2009-05-31      
  blue    2009-06-30
  blue    2016-03-31
  blue    2016-04-30
  ", header = T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


B <- read.table(
  text = "
  B.COL   B.TIME
  blue    2007-01-31
  blue    2008-12-31
  blue    2009-02-28
  blue    2009-04-30
  blue    2009-06-30
  blue    2016-08-31
  ", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution which uses functions from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1995984/5619526) and the `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)

# turn a date into a 'monthnumber' relative to an origin
monnb <- function(d) { 
  lt <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date(d, origin="1900-01-01"))
  lt$year*12 + lt$mon 
  } 

# compute a month difference as a difference between two monnb's
mondf <- function(d1, d2) { monnb(d2) - monnb(d1) }

# iterate over rows of A looking for matches in B
adply(A, 1, function(x)
  B[x$A.COL == B$B.COL & 
      abs(mondf(as.Date(x$A.TIME), as.Date(B$B.TIME))) <= 2,]
)

#     A.COL    A.TIME  B.COL    B.TIME
# 1   blue 2009-01-31  blue 2008-12-31
# 2   blue 2009-01-31  blue 2009-02-28
# 3   blue 2009-02-28  blue 2008-12-31
# 4   blue 2009-02-28  blue 2009-02-28
# 5   blue 2009-02-28  blue 2009-04-30
#  ....
```

#### edit: `data.table` implementation

```
library(data.table)
merge_AB <- data.table(merge(A,B, by.x = 'A.COL', by.y = 'B.COL'))

merge_AB[,DateDiff := abs(mondf(A.TIME, B.TIME))
       ][DateDiff <= 2]

 #     A.COL     A.TIME     B.TIME DateDiff
 # 1:  blue 2009-01-31 2008-12-31        1
 # 2:  blue 2009-01-31 2009-02-28        1
 # 3:  blue 2009-02-28 2008-12-31        2
 # 4:  blue 2009-02-28 2009-02-28        0
 # 5:  blue 2009-02-28 2009-04-30        2
 # ...
```

#### data

```
A <- read.table(
text = "
A.COL   A.TIME          
blue    2009-01-31     
blue    2009-02-28      
blue    2009-03-31      
blue    2009-04-30      
blue    2009-05-31      
blue    2009-06-30
blue    2016-03-31
blue    2016-04-30
", header = T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


B <- read.table(
  text = "
B.COL   B.TIME
blue    2007-01-31
blue    2008-12-31
blue    2009-02-28
blue    2009-04-30
blue    2009-06-30
blue    2016-08-31
", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = T)
```

Comment: Good job! Only one question: Can this also be done with `datatable`? I am not familiar with `plyr` and I just started with `datatable`, so I wonder if it can be used here to achieve the same sorting?
At a sidenote, you did not use `sqldf` to solve this. I wonder: Is not possible in this case?

Comment: @user3032689 Yes we can, see my edit for a `data.table` implementation