# Why is R seq.Date is skipping months

Tags: r

When I want to list all the months between two dates, seq.Date seems to skip dates.  I am definitely making a mistake in my code somewhere, but it is so simple, can't seem to get it right.

Help would be appreciated.

```
seq.Date(as.Date("2017-01-31"),as.Date("2017-06-30"),by = "months")
```

Regards,
Aksel

Comment: Probably safer doing `seq.Date(as.Date("2017-02-01"),as.Date("2017-07-01"),by = "months")`

Comment: Related: [Add/subtract 6 months (bond time) in R using lubridate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628863/add-subtract-6-months-bond-time-in-r-using-lubridate), i.e. the part with "Add and subtract months to a date without exceeding the last day of the new month"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because your dates are the last day of the month, and I believe seq.Date will add the number of days from the month that it started in.

If we look at `diff` of the output from your example:

```
seq.Date(as.Date("2017-01-31"),as.Date("2017-06-30"),by = "months")
[1] "2017-01-31" "2017-03-03" "2017-03-31" "2017-05-01" "2017-05-31"

diff(seq.Date(as.Date("2017-01-31"),as.Date("2017-06-30"),by = "months"))
Time differences in days
[1] 31 28 31 30
```

So it looks like `seq.Date` is adding 31 days because it starts in January, and then adds February's 28 days etc.

Probably better to use different dates, and maybe combining with some lubridate `floor_date` or `ceiling_date`

Comment: Thank you very much!  Explanation was much appreciated as well.

Answer (score 6):

If you really need the last day of the month, one possibility would be to construct a sequence of the first day of the *following* months and then subtract 1 day.  For example:

```
> seq.Date(as.Date("2017-02-01"),as.Date("2017-07-01"),by = "months") - 1
[1] "2017-01-31" "2017-02-28" "2017-03-31" "2017-04-30" "2017-05-31" "2017-06-30"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think another solution might be to reduce your initial date to the first day of the month, and after your sequence is generated, to use the function `LastDayInMonth` from package `bsts`:

```
initial_date <- as.Date("2017-01-31")
day(initial_date) <- 1 # This is only in case you can't use first date of month
# in the initial assignment.
# As when you have several dates and you want to automate process.
desired_sequence <- seq.Date(initial_date,as.Date("2017-06-30"),by = "months")
library(bsts)
desired_sequence <- LastDayInMonth(desired_sequence)
```