# lubridate::floor_date returns NA

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to write a function that, given a date `start` and an integer `n`, adds `n` months to the date and then takes the last day of the resulting month.
The following piece of code, however, returns `NA` for `n=8+12k`, but seems to work in other  cases.

```
library(lubridate)
start <- ymd("2020-06-29")
n <- 8
floor_date(start + months(n), "month") + months(1) - days(1)
>[1] NA
```

I guess this is somewhat due to the existence of leap years, but I still find it puzzling. Plus, I couldn't find anything in the docs about this.

Can someone please explain what is going on, or suggest a better way to do the job?

Comment: This is probably because you're hitting February with the `floor_date()` statement and there with only 28 days, `lubridate` gives an NA when you ask for the 29th

Comment: Try this instead, `add_with_rollback(start, months(n))  + months(1) - days(3)`

Comment: Try `%m+%`, "Add [...] months to a date without exceeding the last day of the new month", as described e.g. here: [Add/subtract 6 months (bond time) in R using lubridate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628863/add-subtract-6-months-bond-time-in-r-using-lubridate/22646010#22646010)

Comment: Thanks @Henrik! I couldn't find that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clock package is really good for this, as it has an explicit argument specifying what you want done with invalid dates.  And also the date_end function. 
I think you want: (R >= 4.1 for native pipe)

```
library(clock)
start <- parse_date("2020-06-29")
n <- 8
start |> add_months(n, invalid = "previous") |> date_end('month')
```

Which gives:
`[1] "2021-02-28"`