# Create sequence of date on every last day of month

Tags: r, date, seq

I'm trying to create a sequence of date on every last day of the months.
For example, the start date is "2018-01-31". I want to create a sequence of every last day of month since the start date.

```
[1] "2018-01-31" "2018-02-28" "2018-03-31" "2018-04-30" "2018-05-31" "2018-06-30"
```

I'm trying to use this syntax:

```
seq(as.Date("2018-01-31",format="%Y-%m-%d"),by="month",length.out=6)
```

But it gives this output instead:

```
[1] "2018-01-31" "2018-03-03" "2018-03-31" "2018-05-01" "2018-05-31" "2018-07-01"
```

How to get the last day of every months since the start date?

Comment: [Add (subtract) months without exceeding the last day of the new month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628863/add-subtract-months-without-exceeding-the-last-day-of-the-new-month)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want last day of month, instead of start from `2018-01-31`, try

```
seq(as.Date("2018-02-01",format="%Y-%m-%d"),by="month",length.out=6) -1
[1] "2018-01-31" "2018-02-28" "2018-03-31" "2018-04-30" "2018-05-31" "2018-06-30"
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use the `lubridate` package and its `%m+%` operator:

```
library(lubridate)

as.Date("2018-01-31") %m+% months(0:5)
#> [1] "2018-01-31" "2018-02-28" "2018-03-31" "2018-04-30" "2018-05-31" "2018-06-30"
```

Answer (score 0):

`tidyverse` has added the [clock](https://clock.r-lib.org/) package *in addition* to the `lubridate` package that has nice functionality for this:

```
library(clock)

date_build(2018, 1:5, 31, invalid = "previous")
[1] "2018-01-31" "2018-02-28" "2018-03-31" "2018-04-30" "2018-05-31"
```

When the date is sequenced, `2018-02-31` is not a valid date. The `invalid` argument makes explicit what to do in this case: go to the last day of the `"previous"` valid date.